# Match data from two tables and return results where something matchs

Tags: mysql, select, join, where-clause

Update 4/25/13 6:25AM: I am using MyISAM

I have searched a lot and am not sure the best way to do this. I have two tables that have matching values in different columns and need to return all that apply to where clause.

Table 1 name `agent`
Relevant Column Names `agent_name` and `team`

Table 2 name `poll_data`
Relevant Column Names `agent` and `duid`

So I want to count how many poll results I get from each teambut I need to somehow add the `team` from `agent` table to `poll_data` by matching the `agent`.`agent_name` to `poll_data`.`name` so I can return only data for that team. How can I match the records and then search them in a single query.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM poll_data JOIN agent ON (agent = agent_name) GROUP BY team`

Comment: you should normalize database. you can add id of team to poll_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this ...

```
$query1="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM poll_data JOIN agent ON (poll_data.agent = agent.agent_name) GROUP BY agent.team";
```

you should normalize the database using foreign key.

Comment: When testing the statement in phpMyAdmin I get an error: #1054 - Unknown column 'poll_data.agent' in 'on clause'

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using MyISAM maybe I should convert it and use foreign keys... The database might get big and I wanted the speed from MyISAM

Comment: I converted to innoDB and setup the foreign key. had to change poll_data.agent to author and I decided to change agetn_name to author as well. Thanks For all the help.